# Scale image down, but not up in latex

Tags: latex

I have a command which includes an includegraphics command - I can pass an image to my command, and it will do some standard formatting for me before actually including the image.  Some of the images that I'm including via this command are smaller than \textwidth, while some are larger.  I'd like to scale the larger images down to \textwidth, while not scaling the smaller images up - this means I can't just do

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img}
```

Is there a way to specify a maxwidth?  Or, can I get the width of the image somehow so I can do something like

```
\ifthenelse{\imagewidth > \textwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img}}{%
    \includegraphics{img}}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the width of the image you can use this code:

```
\newlength{\imgwidth}
\settowidth{\imgwidth}{\includegraphics{img}}
```

You could use this in the document preamble to create a new command to automatically set the width:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\imgwidth}

\newcommand\scalegraphics[1]{%   
    \settowidth{\imgwidth}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
    \setlength{\imgwidth}{\minof{\imgwidth}{\textwidth}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth]{#1}%
}
```

and then, in your document:

```
\scalegraphics{img}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know how many times I looked at \settowidth and decided that it wouldn't work on images for some reason - thanks!

Comment: I would recommend also adding keepaspectratio as one of the arguments to includgraphics.  As the name says, it maintains the aspect ratio of the image when scaling to a specified with.  E.g

\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}

Answer (score 1):

I like an additional parameter for optionally scaling the image down or up a bit, so my version of \scalegraphics looks like this:

```
\newcommand\scalegraphics[2][]{%
    \settowidth{\imgwidth}{\includegraphics{#2}}%
    \setlength{\imgwidth}{\minof{#1\imgwidth}{\textwidth}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth]{#2}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`adjustbox`](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf) package is usefull for this. Below you will find a short example. It allows the following (besides triming, clipping, adding margins and relative scaling:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=3cm]{}}

\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=2\linewidth,height=3cm]{}}

\includegraphics[width=2\linewidth,height=3cm,max width=\linewidth]{}
\end{document}
```

If you use the `export` package option most of its keys can be used directly with `\includegraphics`. FOr instance the key relevant to you, `max width`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to constrain is not an image but a standalone `.tex` file, you can slightly modify ChrisN's `\scalegraphics` to

```
\newlength{\inputwidth}
\newcommand\maxwidthinput[2][\linewidth]{%   
    \settowidth{\inputwidth}{#2}%
    \setlength{\inputwidth}{\minof{\inputwidth}{#1}}%
    \resizebox{\inputwidth}{!}{#2}
}
```

and then use it like so

```
\maxwidthinput{\input{standalone}}
\maxwidthinput[0.5\textwidth]{\input{standalone}}
```

And of course, `adjustbox` as suggested by ted will work as well:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
...
\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{\input{standalone}}
```

Answer (score -4):

After a few minutes of searching through CTAN manuals and Google results, I think I can safely say that what you want to do is either impossible or very hard. My only recommendation is that you have two commands, one for small images and one for large, or one command with an option.

There may be a way, but I leave it to other S.O. LaTeX wizards to provide a better answer.

Edit: I am wrong, see above.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion - although, I've gotten everything figured out except for how to get the width of the image, so I'm really hoping that I can get over that last hurdle.